# Binding Enter Key?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, javascript

here is my script that runs from a CEWP. just want little search button, but it only works when i click the button, enter key just refreshes the page. I've tried the event.preventDefault() - but no luck - it's confusing.

i'm passed the point of no return. i must find a solution to this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function customSearch(inputId,type,site,scope) { 

var searchUrl = site + '/_layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx?'; 

<!-- // Or '/_layouts/SearchResults.aspx?' -->

var searchTerm = '&k=' + document.getElementById(inputId).value;  var listParams = '&cs=This%20' + type + '&u=' + scope; window.location.href = searchUrl + searchTerm + listParams; 

} 

function searchKeyPress(buttonId,e) { 

<!-- // look for window.event in case event isn't passed in -->

if (window.event) {  e = window.event;  } 

if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
    document.getElementById(buttonId).click();  
    }
} 
</script>

<input name="searchBox1" id="searchBox1" onkeypress="searchKeyPress('searchButton1',event);" type="text"/> 

<input name="searchButton1" id="searchButton1" onclick="customSearch( 'searchBox1', 'Site', 'http://RegEng', 'http://RegEng' );" type="button" value="Search"/>
```

Comment: did you also return false after the preventDefault? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter

Comment: yep - my syntax must be bad somewhere. getting an "object doesn't support this prop/method in my debugger at the event.preventDefault. hmmmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a debugger in your function to make sure you are getting the event object correctly. Make sure buttonId and e are the objects that you expect.

Then you need to move the `preventDefault(); return false` to the end of the function because the return false will leave the function and nothing afterwards will get executed:

```
function searchKeyPress(buttonId,e) { 

    <!-- // look for window.event in case event isn't passed in -->

    if (window.event) {  e = window.event;  } 

    if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
        document.getElementById(buttonId).click();
        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: rookie mistake there. thanks. still getting the error though. clearly i don't know what my event is. what do you mean by "add debugger"?

Comment: I updated the answer, if you run that code it should prompt you to debug the code depending on what browser you are using. For IE hit F12 -> Script tab -> start debugging and refresh the page.

Comment: ok cool - so i can see my local vars and step through things - but honestly i'm not even sure what to look for.

Comment: look at the e var, does it look like an event object? Does buttonId look like an event object? Are there any other parameters being passed in? You may have to change the parameters to your function

Comment: OK - so e is a DispCEventObj, and buttonId is a string. are there other parameters? no? yes? argh.

Comment: are u calling e.PreventDefault() instead of event.PreventDefault()?

Comment: no - definitely tried that already. trying it again though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8207/discussion-between-ryan-erickson-and-bill)